# How do I find out duplicate records in sql and do calculation on column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I have one table which has data like this:

```
CUSIP   Quantity  Date           Price
AF0      500000   5/16/2013      1
AE4      400000   5/6/2013      1.0825
AE4      500      5/6/2013      1
```

I need to check column `CUSIP` and `Date` If I have a duplicate `CUSIP` for the same date then I need to do following calculation.

1. Add Quantity for both of them instead of showing duplicate records need to show only one record( sum of Quantity).
2. Recalculate the Price as follows:
   NewPrice = ((400000 * 1.0825) + (500 * 1.00))/(400000 + 500) = 1.08148

For example in using above data Need to show output like

```
CUSIP   Quantity  Date          Price
AF0     500000    5/6/2013      1
AE4     400500    5/6/2013      1.082397004
```

My current SQL query is

```
Select AVG(Price),CUSIP,Quantity,DATE,Price 
from DailyData where a.Date = '25-12-2011'
GROUP BY CUSIP,DATE
```

Plase help me to correct my sql query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select
     CUSIP,
     DATE,
     SUM(Quantity) AS SumQty,
     SUM(Quantity*Price)/SUM(Quantity) AS NewPrice
from
   DailyData a
where
   a.Date = '25-12-2011'
GROUP BY
   CUSIP,DATE
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (CUSIP varchar(50), Quantity int, SomeDate date, Price decimal(19,9));
INSERT @t VALUES
 ('AF0', 500000, '20130516', 1),('AE4', 400000, '20130506',1.0825),('AE4', 500, '20130506', 1)

Select
     CUSIP,
     SomeDate,
     SUM(Quantity) AS SumQty,
     SUM(Quantity*Price)/SUM(Quantity) AS NewPrice
from
   @t a
GROUP BY
   CUSIP,SomeDate
```

Comment: Need to specify `Quantity` also in `GROUP BY`  Statement ?

Comment: @ashuthinks: no. You either aggregate it or GROUP on it: not both